# change css to index.php

Tags: css, joomla

i want to apply templete.css only for index.php or home in joomla and apply mycss.css to other files . how can i do this . please help me

Answer (score 1):

This is rather simple if you don't over think it. Joomla already has a page class suffix available in menu items that will allow you to control the CSS on a page based on the suffix of the page. This gives you ultimate control over each page without having to load differnt style sheets. You just need to add a little bit of code to your index.php file to make it all work.

Somewhere in the head add this php code -

```
   $menu = &JSite::getMenu();
   $active = $menu->getActive();

   if (is_object( $active )) :
     $params = new JParameter( $active->params );
     $pageclass = $params->get( 'pageclass_sfx' );

   endif;
```

Then replace your body tag with this -

```
<body id="<?php echo $pageclass ? $pageclass : 'default'; ?>">
```

If you specify a page class suffix for a menu item, that will be come the ID for the body, otherwise the ID will be "default". This makes it trivial to have page specific CSS.

Comment: Excellent, I always wished "page class suffix" to be applied to the "body" instead of the level of content ... This is going directly to my favorites! Thank you.

Comment: I've always wondered why more template developers don't do this. It's simple, flexible, and easy to teach non-tech admins. This is a standard feature to all of our templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by 2 ways ...

**1) Create 2 Different Joomla Templates :**

One that use template.css and the other use mycss.css then assign it to whatever pages you want.

**2) Add this code to include your CSS file in the desired pages :**

```
<?php if(JRequest::getCmd('Itemid') == 1 ) {?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/mycss.css" type="text/css" />
<?php } ?>
```

And Change the **Itemid** to the Itemid you want to use.

If you want to use mycss.css on all pages except one page you can modify the code to be :

```
<?php if(JRequest::getCmd('Itemid') != 1 ) {?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/mycss.css" type="text/css" />
<?php } ?>
```

That would do it.

Comment: This would work, but it's never a good idea to hard code parameters in to the template file. If the home page menu ever gets replaced with another itemid then the code would stop working. It also does not allow for any flexibility in loading particular styles without having to go in and hard code more itemids.

Comment: Well you are correct... I will post another way to do it by using modules.

Comment: You can add this within the <head> in your template : <jdoc:include type="modules" name="stylesheet" style="none" /> Then from the module manager you can add the <link> to your stylesheet. This would involve minimal coding and greater flexibility.

Comment: Frankly, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922203/change-css-to-index-php/5925224#5925224 is the best solution!

Answer (score -1):

In your "index.php" or "home in joomla" include only the "template.css" file

```
<link href="template.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In your "other Files" include ony the "mycss.css" file

```
<link href="mycss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Hope I understood the question right

Comment: In Joomla there is only index.php in a template, there are no "other files" to put a different style sheet in.